# For loop copying files in command prompt using a substring to name the destination for each file (with delayed expansion)

Tags: for-loop, cmd, copy, substring, environment-variables

I have a directory of files and a seperate directory filled with folders with names that correspond to a substring of the file name.  I'm trying to cycle through a list of files and for each one, where there is a folder with the corresponding substring name, deposit a copy of the file into it.  Where there is no corresponding folder, I need the file to be ignored.  This can't be done in a batch file, it needs to be done in command prompt.

I'm having the problem that the initial response to my command

```
for /f %I in ('dir /b J:\test\test_audio\en * ^| find ".wav"') do (
set var=I
copy J:\test\test_audio\en\%~I J:\test\test_designed_locations\%var:~0,5%\
)
```

is `The syntax of the command is incorrect`, due I think to the order of expansion of the command.

```
....
C:\Windows\System32>(
set var=Ev164_en.wav
copy J:\test\test_audio\en\Ev164_en.wav J:\test\test_designed_locations\%var:~0,5%\
)
The syntax of the command is incorrect

C:\Windows\System32>(
set var=Ev178_en.wav
copy J:\test\test_audio\en\Ev178_en.wav J:\test\test_designed_locations\%var:~0,5%\
)
The syntax of the command is incorrect
...
```

This would also explain why running the command a second time creates a situation where the substring from the last file is used in all commands, causing every file to be deposited in the last folder and none in the others.

```
....
for /f %I in ('dir /b J:\test\test_audio\en * ^| find ".wav"') do (
set var=I
copy J:\test\test_audio\en\157_en.wav J:\test\test_designed_locations\Ev225\
)
    1 file(s) copied.
for /f %I in ('dir /b J:\test\test_audio\en * ^| find ".wav"') do (
set var=I
copy J:\test\test_audio\en\158_en.wav J:\test\test_designed_locations\Ev225\
)
    1 file(s) copied.
....
```

I suspect that I need to use delayed expansion to stop environment variables being processed and overwriting each other before use.  I've tried adding `setLocal enableDelayedExpansion` at the start of the command and wrapping the reference to the variable in bangs

```
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f %I in ('dir /b J:\test\test_audio\en * ^| find ".wav"') do (
set var=%I
copy J:\test\test_audio\en\%~I J:\test\test_designed_locations\!var:~0,5!\
)
```

With or without the an escape before the comma, I get

```
....
C:\Windows\System32>(
set var=Ev164_en.wav
copy J:\test\test_audio\en\Ev164_en.wav J:\test\test_designed_locations\!var:~0,5!\
)
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
....
```

The variable isn't being processed for its value.  I'm starting to wonder if it's actually possible to for-loop through all the files and use a substring from each file name to identify where to put that file, all in one command.  Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd /v /q /c "pushd "j:\test\test_audio\en" && ( for %a in (*.wav) do ( set "I=%~nxa" & if exist "!I:~0,5!\" copy "%a" "!I:~0,5!" ) & popd )"
```

You can use delayed expansion from command line only if the `cmd` instance is started with it enabled.

**edited** to adapt to comments

```
pushd "j:\test\test_audio\en" && (for %a in (*.wav) do (set "I=%~nxa" & call pushd ^"%I:~0,5^%^" 2>nul &&(copy "%~fa" & popd)) & popd)
```

Well, it can be done without starting a separate `cmd` instance to enable delayed expansion, but the needed escaping to use a `call` to force a second parser evaluation of the line is not very obvious.

Comment: Thanks @MC ND. With arguments starting the cmd instance with delayed expansion enabled presumably? This wasn't offered to me in initial parameters but might be available. Does that mean that this problem is impossible to solve in command line if I don't use delayed expansion? The job is to integrate with someone else's program and what I've listed in the question are the parameters they gave me. I'm wondering now if there's a way around this given current parameters or whether I need to go back to renegotiate them with the other guy.

Comment: @gianthair, answer updated. The parser removes read operations inside blocks of code replacing them with the value inside variables. If a variable changes its value inside a block you can not retrieve the changed value as the read operations were removed. You need delayed expansion or use the `call` command over a escaped string to force a second parser evaluation. There is another alternative IF the file names can be splitted using the underscore, using an aditional `for /f` to handle the splitting, but i don't know if this is the case.